# shift() algorithm help to understand in code

Tags: javascript

```js
function sortArray(array) {
  let newArr = array.filter((el) => el % 2).sort((a, b) => a - b);

  return array.map((p) => (p % 2 ? newArr.shift() : p));
}
console.log(sortArray([5, 8, 6, 3, 4]));

// Output: [ 3, 8, 6, 5, 4 ]
```

Please, kindly, help to understand code - exactly? As I understand firstly we filter initial array and get resut in newArr: [3, 5] = newArr; than we mapping initial array and try to check whether p % 2 or not, if yes, we leave the even number in array, if no, we delete with shift()... in newArr The questions is - how the elements pushed and deleted, replaced in initial array? I don't understand the steps since shift() function is started...  Thank you si much!!!

```
newArr.shift()
```

Comment: It replaces odd elements in the original array (`array`) with the sorted odd elements from `newArr`, keeping the even elements unchanged.

Comment: yeah, I understand logically checking the code... but i confused as general option of shift is to delete first element in array))).

Comment: `.shift()` removes the first element from the `newArr` but also returns it as well, which is what the current element in the `.map()` gets "transformed" (ie: mapped) to.

Comment: Am I correctly understand? mapping el = 5(index = 0) in array, shift it in newArr and replace 5 with 3 in array (as 3 in newArr was at 0 index)?

Comment: The function filters the odd numbers in the array and reinserts them(by using map() function) in the new array it generates so that the odd numbers are ordered. Even numbers remain in the same position.

Comment: Thank you so much for clear explanation!!!